# I have a stored List data and how can I localize it in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-localizations

I can translate the text inside the widget using AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translated and it work fine

However, when I want to localize a stored List<> data which will be used in listView Builder, I am not able to do so, since it need (context).

My question is how to localize a stored list data(outside widget) and pass to list view builder?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do 2 things

In case if you have a list in another file, then it should be static like this:

```
class Presets {
  static var presetData = [];
}
```

after you loaded up your list, you can do these steps:

**First,**
*Create Widgets as children like this:*

```
List<Widget> presetsLoadUp() {
  List<Widget> children = <Widget>[];
  for(i < yourList.length){
    children.add(Text(yourList[i]));
  }
  return children;
}
```

You can create your own unique widget inside the *children.add* method.

**Secondly,**
*Create the list:*

```
...
child: ListView(
                    children: presetsLoadUp(),
                  ),
```

Comment: thanks, I just use a outside widget to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has similar problem, please take it for reference.
I just build another widget to solve this.
What I do is :
build another widget,
then put the list data inside and
return ListViewBuilder.
Everything is same,
just put your list data inside another widget can solve the problem